# Why does passing a dictionary as part of *args give us only the keys?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, variadic-functions, variadic

##### The setup

Let's say I have a function:

```py
def variadic(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Positional:", args)
    print("Keyword:", kwargs)
```

Just for experiment's sake, I call it with the following:

```py
variadic({'a':5, 'b':'x'}, *{'a':4, 'b':'y'}, **{'a':3, 'b':'z'})
```

Output:

```py
Positional: ({'a': 5, 'b': 'x'}, 'a', 'b')
Keyword: {'a': 3, 'b': 'z'}
```

##### The problem

I don't have an issue with the keyword arguments.

For the positional ones, however, we get the tuple `({'a': 5, 'b': 'x'}, 'a', 'b')`. I understand why we get the first element (`{'a': 5, 'b': 'x'}`), but I am surprised that we are getting only the keys (`a`, `b`) from `{'a':4, 'b':'y'}`. I don't understand why this is happening. I think I expected an error from passing a dictionary to `*args` instead.

##### Possible answers?

I have not been able to find an answer, but suspect that when parsing `*args` Python does something along the lines:

```py
for arg in args:
    do something
```

and since we passed a dictionary, and iterating over a dictionary like this (as opposed to `d.items()`) gives us only the keys, we just get the keys. Can anyone confirm that or clear up why this is happening?

Comment: Hint: Look at `list({'a': 1, 'b': 2})`. The behavior is general "what happens when you iterate over a dict?" behavior, not anything specific to `*args`.

Comment: You're on the right track, the `*` operator does iterable unpacking. The dictionary iterable is the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: That clears it up. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function call, an argument prefixed with a `*` must be an iterable value. Each value produced by iterating over the argument is provided to the function as a separate positional argument. (Note that this is independent of a *paraemter* prefixed with a `*`, which collects positional arguments not assigned to any other parameter into a tuple.)

Values of type `dict` are iterable; the iterator for a `dict` yields the *keys* of the `dict`.